# How to access local system files from a docker container?

Tags: docker

I am working on a docker terminal. I want to access local files from the docker terminal. Is there a way to do it?? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have a large number of files to access

I tried loading using the absolute path but it showed that the file wasn't found

Comment: If you didn't mount the files using a volume then no, there is no way.

Comment: In the dockerfile, you could use ADD.  If the container is running, you could use docker cp to copy the files in.  You could also run with a mounted volume - which would be my recommendation.

Comment: One of the major design goals of Docker is that a container can't normally access the host filesystem.  If your application principally needs to work on local files, it will often be much easier to run it without involving Docker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can access local files from within a Docker container. There are a few different approaches you can take:

Mounting a Volume: When you run your Docker container, you can specify a volume to mount. This allows you to share files between your local file system and the container. For example:

```
docker run -v /path/to/local/files:/path/inside/container image_name
```

Replace `/path/to/local/files` with the absolute path to your local files and `/path/inside/container` with the path where you want to access these files inside the container.

Copying Files: If you prefer not to mount volumes, you can copy files into your Docker container when you build it. In your Dockerfile, you can use the COPY instruction to copy files from your local file system into the container.

Docker CP Command: If you need to copy files into or out of a running container, you can use the docker cp command. For example, to copy a file named example.txt from a running container named my_container to your local file system, you would use:

```
docker cp my_container:/path/inside/container/example.txt /path/to/local/files/example.txt
```